# How to get inventory_item_id from /product_listings API endpoint

Tags: shopify

Doing a fetch of items from the `/admin/products.json` endpoint yields me products, with variants, that have `inventory_item_id` in each variant.

Doing a fetch of items from the `/admin/product_listings` gets me products, with variants, that DONT have `inventory_item_id` in each variant.

Because my app should only fetch products that have been specifically exposed to my channel, and thus from `/admin/product_listings` endpoint, this is a problem. I need that `inventory_item_id` property.

What are my options here? How can I fetch `inventory_item_id`s for all products exposed to a channel?

One idea I had was:

1. Fetch all items exposed to my app's channel <strike>(which is already an extremely bandwidth expensive operation)</strike> (Just get product ids)
2. <strike>Extract or `.map` the product ids</strike>
3. Go back to the `/admin/products` endpoint to fetch products, with their respective variants, and thus their `inventory_item_ids`.

But that seems... ridiculous? Am I missing something basic here?

---

Edit: Upon further research, it seems that I can just get the `product_id`s exposed to my app, but it would still require another trip to Shopify to get the very extensive array of products just to have variants populated with `inventory_item_id`

Comment: You have not explained why you need that inventory_item_id value. It is of concern to the merchant at fulfullment time, not product browsing time. Why are your shorts in a knot for it?

Comment: Because I need make a call to the `InventoryLevel` api to get the inventory at a specific location. I cannot do this without the `inventory_item_id` or  `location_id`.

Comment: Shopify is not currently supporting a front-end that displays inventory per location, or heck, even inventory levels. Too many people were poaching inventory numbers which makes total sense. So you are on your own to hack your own solution, super easy, but yes, work for you.

Comment: I don't need the `inventory_quantity`, only the `inventory_item_id`. I understand why they might not want to display the quantity to the front end, but one couldn't glean anything from an `inventory_item_id`, lest a call to the admin api is made. In which case, you'd need a token.

Comment: You're contradicting yourself. You say you want quantity per location and now you say you don't need quantity...

Comment: Whether or not I need the `quantity` is besides the point – all I need is the `inventory_item_id`. Yes, later, I *might* need to get the inventory quantity specifically, but it's not why I'm asking the question... I want to know if there is a reason for why the `inventory_item_id` is not included in products` variants from `product_listings`. Including it would be of zero-harm, because as I said earlier, you cannot glean any inventory quantity details from just the id itself.

Comment: My advice to you is simple. Solve your problem this way. Install an App in your shop with scope/permission to read products, inventory and locations. Add an App Proxy to said App. Now from the shop itself, the front-end, you can code up an XHR call that will return the complete JSON of inventory for your use. End of problems and issues.